# Heroku run shows update, is it necessary to update ? And if yes than how?

Tags: heroku, updates

```
heroku run rails console

▸    heroku-cli: update available from 6.11.17 to 6.14.16-9ae58fc

▸    No app specified
```

How do I update my `heroku-cli` version?

Answer (score 93):

You are not obligated to update. I am using a previous version as well, and everything works fine.

But if you want to update check this link: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli

It says that to update your heroku cli you just have to do this:

```
heroku update
```

But there is this issue:

> Not all methods of installation are updatable with heroku update. Apt users will have to use `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade heroku`. npm/yarn users will have to update with npm upgrade -g heroku-cli or yarn global upgrade heroku-cli
>
> If updating does not update the CLI, try uninstalling with the uninstall instructions below

Comment: of note: as of this writing, heroku has a major version upgrade (8) available, but the version installed through apt is still on version 7. Don't worry about it--after wasting half an hour, I eventually concluded 7 was fine.

Answer (score 3):

```
heroku update
```

did not work for me. I had to run:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install heroku
```

in order to get an update.

Answer (score 1):

I am using Windows 11 and `heroku update` is working properly.

Remember to run this command in the terminal as an administrator.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall Heroku by using command:

```
sudo apt-get remove Heroku
```

Then install Heroku by:

```
sudo apt-get install heroku
```

Now check Heroku version:

```
heroku -v
```

Answer (score -1):

This is how I updated:

```
npm update -g heroku
```